# error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "galileo-io" "johnny-five"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yocto, intel-galileo

When I try to install galileo-io and johnny-five on the Galileo gen1 Yocto bigger image from this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/galileo-io#galileo-io-is-compatible-with-intel-s-galileo-generation-1-galileo-generation-2-and-edison-boards-mini-and-arduino-board-sparkfun-gpio-arduino-blocks-xadow-board-dfrobot-romeo-io-expansion) I get the following error. Any idea how to fix this?

```
root@clanton:~# npm install galileo-io johnny-five
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.7-yocto-standard
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "galileo-io" "johnny-f                                                                                        ive"
npm ERR! cwd /home/root
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.2
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here's the npm log:

```
root@clanton:~# cat npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'galileo-io',
1 verbose cli   'johnny-five' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.2
3 info using node@v0.8.18
4 verbose read json /home/root/package.json
5 verbose read json /home/root/package.json
6 verbose cache add [ 'galileo-io', null ]
7 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="galileo-io" args=["galileo-io",null]
8 verbose parsed url { pathname: 'galileo-io',
8 verbose parsed url   path: 'galileo-io',
8 verbose parsed url   href: 'galileo-io' }
9 verbose cache add [ 'johnny-five', null ]
10 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="johnny-five" args=["johnny-five",null]
11 verbose parsed url { pathname: 'johnny-five',
11 verbose parsed url   path: 'johnny-five',
11 verbose parsed url   href: 'johnny-five' }
12 silly lockFile d36599c0-galileo-io galileo-io
13 verbose lock galileo-io /home/root/.npm/d36599c0-galileo-io.lock
14 silly lockFile da7ffa14-johnny-five johnny-five
15 verbose lock johnny-five /home/root/.npm/da7ffa14-johnny-five.lock
16 silly lockFile d36599c0-galileo-io galileo-io
17 silly lockFile da7ffa14-johnny-five johnny-five
18 verbose addNamed [ 'galileo-io', '' ]
19 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
20 silly lockFile 61ff2031-galileo-io galileo-io@
21 verbose lock galileo-io@ /home/root/.npm/61ff2031-galileo-io.lock
22 verbose addNamed [ 'johnny-five', '' ]
23 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
24 silly lockFile 22931f58-johnny-five johnny-five@
25 verbose lock johnny-five@ /home/root/.npm/22931f58-johnny-five.lock
26 silly addNameRange { name: 'galileo-io', range: '', hasData: false }
27 silly addNameRange { name: 'johnny-five', range: '', hasData: false }
28 verbose url raw galileo-io
29 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './galileo-io' ]
30 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
31 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 00:29:54
32 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
33 verbose url raw johnny-five
34 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './johnny-five' ]
35 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
36 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 00:29:54
37 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
38 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
39 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
40 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 00:30:05
41 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
42 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
43 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 00:30:05
44 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/johnny-five
45 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
46 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 00:31:05
47 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io
48 silly lockFile 61ff2031-galileo-io galileo-io@
49 error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
49 error     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
49 error     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
50 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
50 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
50 error or email it to:
50 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
51 error System Linux 3.8.7-yocto-standard
52 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "galileo-io" "johnny-five"
53 error cwd /home/root
54 error node -v v0.8.18
55 error npm -v 1.2.2
56 error syscall getaddrinfo
57 error code ENOTFOUND
58 error errno ENOTFOUND
59 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
root@clanton:~#
```

Here's what I get from wget:

```
root@clanton:/# wget https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five.git
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five.git
```

and without `s` in `https` I have:

```
root@clanton:/# wget http://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five.git                 wget: bad address 'github.com'
```

Comment: The log says it can't find the address [`https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io`](https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io). You could try visiting that address in a browser and see if you can get to it, but there's not much else we can do to help, as it appears to be a network issue.

Comment: I can browse to it from my browser not from within the board using Putty. `root@clanton:/# ping: bad port spec 'https://registry.npmjs.org/galileo-io'
-sh: ping:: command not found` any idea how that could be fixed?

Comment: The wget package in some distros cannot use https. You'll need to recompile it to do so. Search online for "wget https" for more on that, and the yocto forums perhaps as well.

Comment: use curl => curl -L https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five.git > /tmp/johnny-five.git